# ¿Cómo hacer consulta de rango de edades en SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, join, sql

Tengo una base de datos con la información de todos los contagios de Covid-19 hasta la fecha, la cual es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me falta hacer estas 2 consultas, si es posible utilizar `joins` mucho mejor.

- Rango de edad de mayor cantidad de fallecidos
- Rango de edad de mayor cantidad de personas recuperadas

Comment: ¿Y cuales son los rangos que manejas?

Comment: No tengo uno establecido

Comment: Si esto no es un ejercicio escolar, es importante que se regrese al diseño de la base de datos para normalizar las tablas. Si esto avanza de esta forma, todo va a complicarse cada vez más.

Comment: No entiendo entonces, si no tienes definidos los rangos como piensas saber cual es el que tiene mayor cantidad de algo? a menos claro que lo que busques es justamente encontrar estos rangos, en cuyo caso es más un problema de estadística que de SQL.

Comment: Me refiero a que los rangos es los que uno quiera

Answer (score 1):

Un *rango* de edades, es fácil de determinar de manera aritmética si todos los rangos tienen la misma longitud. Por ejemplo, para rangos de 5 años, los rangos serían estos:

```
 0   0- 4 años
 1   5- 9 años
 2  10-14 años
    ...
17  85-89 años
18  90-94 años
    etc..
```

He puesto intencionalmente el índice del lado izquierdo, porque

- El número de índice del rango al que pertenece una edad se puede obtener fácilmente dividiendo la edad dentro de la longitud del período, por ejemplo, si un paciente tiene 47 años, 47 / 5 es 9, por lo que está en el rango con índice 9.
- Las edades límite del rango se pueden calcular fácilmente teniendo el número de índice, pues para el índice 10, el rango va de 50 a 54. 50 es (10 * 5) y 54 es (11 * 5 - 1)

Estoy asumiendo que el campo *edad* almacenado es un número entero, si no habría que forzarlo con un `cast(edad as int)` para que esto funcione.

Con esto, una consulta básica que nos da un contador, por rango de edad, de los casos recuperados, sería:

```
select   Edad / 5 IndiceRango
       , count(1) ContadorRecuperados
  from Casos
 where fecha_recuperado is not null
 group by Edad / 5
```

Para obtener el rango con más recuperados, ordenamos descendentemente por el contador y nos quedamos con el primer registro:

```
select top 1
         Edad / 5 IndiceRango
       , count(1) NumeroDeRecuperados
  from Casos
 where fecha_recuperado is not null
 group by Edad / 5
 order by count(1) desc
```

Construir la descripción del rango, con la explicación que he dado, debiera resultar dentro del alcance y queda como ejercicio para el lector. De igual manera, se puede hacer con rangos variables:

```
declare @LongitudRango int = 10;

select Edad / @LongitudRango IndiceRango
... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN age_c < 18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Under 18],
        SUM(CASE WHEN age_c BETWEEN 18 AND 24 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [18-24],
        SUM(CASE WHEN age_c BETWEEN 25 AND 34 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [25-34]
 FROM contacts
```

Para más información puedes visitar el post original
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762886/sql-group-by-age-range